# Compiling Less files into separate css files using Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, less

I have my index.js which has following imports

```
import "./less/home.less";
import "./less/dashboard.less";
```

So now, I want the webpack to create two separate css files for me. `home.css` and `dashboard.css`.

How do I achieve this using `less-loader` `css-loader` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin`

This is my webpack config file.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");


const extractLess = new ExtractTextPlugin({filename:'stylesheets/[name].css'});

    module.exports = {
        entry : "./index.js",
        output : {
            path : path.resolve(__dirname),
            publicPath : '/',
            filename : "bundle.js"
        },
        module : {
            rules : [
            {
                test : /\.less$/,
                use : extractLess.extract(['css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
            }]
        },
        plugins : [extractLess],
        resolve : {
            extensions : ['.js'],
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work by updating your code

```
module : {
            rules : [
            {
                test : /\.less$/,
                use : extractLess.extract(['css-loader', 'less-loader' ]),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ 
                       loader:[ 'css', 'less' ], 
                       fallbackLoader: 'style-loader' 
                 })
            }]
        },
```

Comment: I think ExtractTextPlugin does not have Webpack 4 support. Try https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin